# c# Access inserting new data to table with autonumber

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a table with these columns:

```
PersonID AutoNumber PrimaryKey
TCKimlikNo Number
PersonName Text
PersonSurname Text
Address Text
Birthdate Text
CategoryID Number
```

When im trying to insert value from c# I am using this query:

```
INSERT INTO Person(TCKimlikNo, PersonName, PersonSurname, Adress, BirthDate, CategoryID) 
VALUES(@tcKimlikNo, @personName, @personSurname, @adress, @birthDate, @categoryId)
```

But it says:

> "Microsoft Access set 1
>   field to Null due to type conversion
>   failure, and it didn't add 0 record(s)
>   to the table due to key violations, 0
>   record(s) due to lock violations, and
>   0 record(s) due to validation rule
>   violations."

I think the error occuring because of that autonumber column. Access trying to insert null value to that, but field wont let it.  In SQL this query works perfectly. But Access is just annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NULL value is because of a type conversion issue.  Most likely you are passing data into one of your fields that cannot be converted by Access into the data type that it is expecting.  I would guess that you are passing in a value to CategoryID that is not converting to a proper number.  This could also be true of the TCKimlinkNo field.  I believe if the string field is too short for the passed-in values, it will just truncate them so I doubt this is the issue.

Also, don't forget to check the size of your number fields.  Is the number you are entering larger than the number allowed?  Are you sending decimal data when it is expecting a whole number?

The autonumber won't be a problem unless you are trying to write to it (which you don't appear to be doing.

Comment: I looked up again and the problem was "TCKimlikNo" column, im trying to insert a number like "123456789012" which was too big for that column. So its giving me error.
Thanks for answer.